# Rails button to disable if data is in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a button that i need disabling if the data it was going to submit already exists in the database.

Bare in mind ive only been using this for like a month. so im a super noob!! haha!

The button is this `<%= link_to 'Table', admin_table_statuses_path(table_id: @table.id), class: "btn btn-primary", method: :post, remote: true%>`

my controller for this button is pretty basic also. see here

```
def create
    table_id = params[:table_id] #Keep the same
    @table_status = tableStatus.new
    @table_status.table_id = params[:table_id]
    @table_status.invoiced_out_user_id = current_user.id
    @table_status.invoiced_out_datetime = DateTime.now
    if @table_status.save
    # Success
      flash[:notice] = "Done!"
    else
      flash[:notice] = "Fail"
    end
```

Comment: So you want to check if the data exists before the user submits the data? While possible, it'd probably just be easiest to reload the page with the flash that you've already included.

Comment: I agree with nicholas, It would be easier to just let the @table_status.save handle it and if it doesn't save, then the "Fail" message is shown to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give an ID to the button:

```
<%= link_to 'Table', admin_table_statuses_path(table_id: @table.id), class: "btn btn-primary", id: 'create_button',method: :post, remote: true%>
```

Inside create method do:

```
def create
.
.
.
  render :update do |page|
    if @table_status.save
      page << "document.getElementById('create_button').setAttribute('href', '')"
    end
  end
end
```

Since, the element is a **link** not **button**, you can just remove it's href, so that it doesn't hit create method again.